# How to set system date to one day later in macosx

Tags: macos

In macosx, i can set system time to a static time, such as 2013-01-30 16:43:55 by

```
date 013016432013
```

But if i use this command to set date, i should check the date and month because of 30/31 day and add year if after 12-30. This is inconvenient. So who can tell me if there is a method to set date by a interval, for example, i want to set it to one day later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date`'s `-v` option to adjust the output date; for example, `date -v+3d` will print the date 3 days from now. If you want to set the system date like this, you need to run `date` twice, once to get what the date will be in a day, then again to set the system date to that:

```
sudo date $(date -v+1d +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)
```